# How to Disable Lock Key on iMac M1 Magic Keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, apple-silicon

I bought a magic keyboard for my MacBook (to use with a stand). They now have lock key in the top right corner instead of Touch ID - if you press it it logs you out.

It's positioned so I accidentally hit it while doing work and get logged out. Also it's pretty useless.

Is there any way to make it dysfunctional other than using key-logging software like Karabiner? System Preferences > Keyboard > Modifier Keys don't have that option.

Comment: You should have been sent a TouchID keyboard with an M1 iMac. How come you got the old Intel-compatible one instead?

Comment: I ordered another one in different language.

Comment: Not having access to a keyboard like this, some suggestions: Have you tried if you can re-assign a function for this key? Maybe a new macro will do the trick? Have you tried Keyboard Maestro (https://www.keyboardmaestro.com/) or another macro app to reprogram the Lock key? Have you tried System Preferences > Keyboard > Modifier Keys > [The key you want] > No Action?

Comment: I know about the option but I'd rather try another fix if it exists. Not very keen on buying a product just to fix one key, unless it's absolutely last option.

Answer (score 6):

in my case i didnot find any way in any where , in following i show how disable it physically[image]

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). You can also [add a bounty](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/317097)

Comment: there is not any answer other than this

Comment: As inventive as your solution is, it still isn't an answer which relies on software or hardware.

Comment: @IconDaemon I disagree: it's a hardware solution!

Comment: Well ... if that is chewing gum, it started off as software, morphed to firmware, then solidified into hardware. You gotta do what you gotta do.

Comment: I would file this under the category of "field engineering"

Comment: Haha really funny but it seems to actually work except if you're someone smashing the keyboard :)

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Karabiner Elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/) to change the function of this key. Choose **Magic Keyboard with Touch ID (Apple)** as your Target device. Then you can change the Touch ID on the Magic Keyboard key to something else. I chose <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

Comment: Worked as expected. Personally, had to select "Lock key on Magic Keyboard without Touchbar" for it to work.

Answer (score 4):

The question is "is there any way to make it dysfunctional?"

I snipped a piece off the end of a twist-tie and jammed it under the outside corner of the key.  It's dysfunctional.  Pull it out, and the key works again.